# Loading .js file from cache when jQuery.html()

Tags: jquery, html, caching

When I make a call from a javascript file through the ".html" jQuery, the URL is mapped so that it is forced to update javascript file. as an example:

```
$(".r").html(data+'<script text="text/javascript" src="http://../test.js"></script>');
```

The result I got when the call is made by jQuery is loading the file with the following URL:

```
Request URL: http://../test.js?_=1383736176662
```

And so every time the call is made it creates a new URI String "?_=" with random numbers which prevents the file ".js" is loaded from the cache.

Does anyone have any idea how to pull this string of the URI to load the file from the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the script using an `ajax` call and you can manually set the caching to false...

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://../test.js",
  cache: true,
  dataType: "script"
});
```

Comment: Does this option will affect other jQuery ajax calls?

Comment: I will give you a +1 then.

Comment: @Archer - what? `.ajax` or `.ajaxSetup`?

Comment: @imsiso My original answer was to set the global defaults for all ajax calls so that caching was turned off, but as pointed out by codingstill that would affect every other ajax call, so I modified my answer so that the script is loaded in a distinct call that has caching turned off.  This will not have any affect on any other ajax calls that the op may or may not have.

Comment: Let me see if I understand perfectly. The right would I remove the tag <script src="test.js"> and make loading the "test.js" in another ajax?

Comment: @AntonioJr Yes, exactly.  This way you have more control over how the script is loaded.  It still does the same thing.

Comment: Another faux pas - this is not my day!  I've fixed the answer now.  Caching should be turned on (true) to remove the trailing number.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the built-in feature of `.html()` that fetches external scripts, but still want to use cache, then you can control this with `$.ajaxSetup`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
$(".r").html(data+'<script src="http://../test.js"></script>');
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Or monkey-patch `$.fn.html`: to turn on cache when applied:

```
$.fn.html = (function($html) {
  return function() {
    var cache = $.ajaxSetup()['cache'];
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: true});
    var ret = $html.apply($(this), arguments);
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: cache});
    return ret;
  };
}($.fn.html));
```